# Create XML from Master detail rows in SQL Server or powerBuilder

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have master detail data from SQL Server like below and wanted to generate XML as per below format to send as SOAP XML from PowerBuilder.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders
    (
    OrderNo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PakDesc varchar(50) NOT NULL
    )  
GO

INSERT INTO Orders values('11111','Test1' )
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Components
    (
    OrderNo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CompNo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CompDesc varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Qty int NOT NULL
    )  
GO

INSERT INTO Components values('11111','01234', 'Comp1', 10 )
INSERT INTO Components values('11111','56789', 'Comp2', 5 )
GO
```

**Desired XML Output**

```
<entrylist>
   <name>OrderNo</name>
   <value>11111</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
   <name>PakDesc</name>
   <value>Test1</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
   <name>CompNo1</name>
   <value>01234</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
   <name>CompDesc1</name>
   <value>Comp1</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
   <name>Qty1</name>
   <value>10</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
   <name>CompNo2</name>
   <value>56789</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
   <name>CompDesc2</name>
   <value>Comp2</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
   <name>Qty2</name>
   <value>5</value>
</entrylist>
```

In PowerBuilder, i get these data in Datawindow and i can navigate each row and column and create a XML elemnt using CREATE PBDOM_Element.

But I was wondering if there is any other way i can easily generate similar XML? 
Can this be generated in SQL Server like this output?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: I am requesting how to generate XML output in the above desired format from a Master Detail data. All the data are varchar except Qty which is int. I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: #1 is missing. Please edit your original post, and provide it.

Comment: Added DDL with data Population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on XQuery FLWOR expression.

It is a two step process in a single T-SQL statement.

First, to simulate master/details structure, we create a raw XML that holds master data as attributes, and details as elements. Second, we shape the final output XML via FLWOR expression.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Orders TABLE (OrderNo varchar(10) NOT NULL, PakDesc varchar(50) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @Orders values('11111','Test1' );

DECLARE @Components TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderNo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CompNo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CompDesc varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Qty int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Components VALUES
('11111','01234', 'Comp1', 10 )
,('11111','56789', 'Comp2', 5 );
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT 
(
SELECT o.OrderNo AS [@OrderNo], o.PakDesc AS [@PakDesc]
    --, c.ID AS [@ID]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.OrderNo) AS [@ID]
    , c.CompNo, c.CompDesc, c.Qty
FROM @Orders AS o LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    @Components AS c ON c.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('
for $y in /root/r   (: master level :)
    let $index := $y/@ID
    return (if ($index eq 1) then
        (
            for $z in $y/@*[local-name(.) ne "ID"]  (: all attributes except @ID :)
            return <entrylist>
                        <name>{local-name($z)}</name>
                        <value>{data($z)}</value>
                    </entrylist>
        )
        else ()
    ,
    for $x in $y/*  (: details level :)
    return <entrylist>
                <name>{concat(local-name($x), $index)}</name>
                <value>{data($x)}</value>
            </entrylist>)
');
```

> Output

```
<entrylist>
  <name>OrderNo</name>
  <value>11111</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
  <name>PakDesc</name>
  <value>Test1</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
  <name>CompNo1</name>
  <value>01234</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
  <name>CompDesc1</name>
  <value>Comp1</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
  <name>Qty1</name>
  <value>10</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
  <name>CompNo2</name>
  <value>56789</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
  <name>CompDesc2</name>
  <value>Comp2</value>
</entrylist>
<entrylist>
  <name>Qty2</name>
  <value>5</value>
</entrylist>
```

Comment: Awesome.. Never knew about FLWOR. Appreciate your help.
For Master data, I see hard coded tags but detail is taken dynamically. is there any possible to make that too dynamic so that in case if we add a new column to master table it picks up?

Comment: @Sak, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. The answer on your question is yes, it is possible. You just need to add one more `for ... in ...` construct to process attributes dynamically.

Comment: I changed query to use LEFT OUTER JOIN in scenarios where master only data exist. But it didn't return result as ID is 0.. So I created like this but it doesn't seem to return as expected. I am missing something..

SELECT 
(
SELECT OrderNo AS [@OrderNo], PakDesc AS [@PakDesc]
 FROM @Orders 
FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('
for $y in /root/r
    return 
    <entrylist>
        <name>{local-name($y)}</name>
        <value>{data($y)}</value>
    </entrylist>
');

Comment: I modified the answer. I changed (1) how ID is calculated and (2) dynamic attributes handling.

Comment: It works great but facing a new issue today. In the above example, if i want to order by c.CompDesc desc, So i added that to Query and results doesn't seem to return as expected. Comp2 should be as  CompDesc1 and Comp1 will be CompDesc2.

Looks like i figured it out.. I used order by o.OrderNo, c.CompDesc desc looks good. 
Thanks again!

Comment: @Sak, good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you, and you can make further adjustments to accommodate your needs. Please connect with me on LinkedIn.